# After placing a comment my 2 divs will be placed under each other

Tags: html, css

I am making 2 forms on 1 page and i want them to be next to each other, I got them next to each other when no comment is placed, but whenever I place a comment they are getting placed **under** each other.

This is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #edf0f2;
}

textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 630px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #5bb112;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
  resize: none;
}

.Changelog {
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 800px;
}

.comment-box {
  width: 630px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #5bb112;
  margin-top: 8px;
  align-content: left;
}

.comment-box p {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #282828;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*-------Changelog---------*/

#maindiv {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#first {
  width: 50%;
}

#second {
  width: 50%
}

.changelog-box {
  width: 630px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #5bb112;
  margin-top: 8px;
  align-content: left;
}

.changelog-box p {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #282828;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div id='maindiv'>
    <div id='first'>

      <form method='POST' action=''>
        <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='date' value='2019-07-04'>
        <textarea name='message'></textarea><br>
        <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'> Comment </button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id='second'>


      <form method='POST' action=''>
        <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='date' value='2019-07-04'>
        <textarea name='message'></textarea><br>
        <button type='submit' name='changelogSubmit'> Comment </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like they have my 2 forms with comment section **next to each other**.

Comment: what do mean by next? its vertically or horizontally ?

Comment: @Irin i want them to stay horizontally, but when i place a comment at comment box 1 they will move under (vertically) each other, but when i make a comment at comment box 2 they will both stay horizontally next to each other and its all fine.

Comment: the structure of your html is completely wrong. Why are you using multiple `html` and `body` tags?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], i.e. the code with the comment inserted?

Comment: @AdityaSrivast That is probably caused by my .inc.php files where i inserted the  `body` and `html` tags

Comment: @MrLister i have tried to remove all unnecessary code

Comment: i have update the code please check it @Basickz

Comment: @Irin where can i see this? (i'm new to this forum)

Comment: @Irin i have some screenshots here from how i want it to be and how it is now.

[How it is without comment]
(https://gyazo.com/9b3c14c03b9a1ac6e00da39bb70e2cc7)

[How it is with comment in second comment section](https://gyazo.com/ec890cd7a12b5f3e0733b9bc0160d187)

[how it is with comment in first comment section](https://gyazo.com/1d7656fba3ece4af0a59dd329ed15200)

Comment: @Basickz I am unable to access comment box here. Please provide minimum code so that we can reproduce your error

Comment: @AdityaSrivast do you mean the php code? Because when i run the snippet code i see the box

Comment: @Basickz the html for your comment box

Comment: @AdityaSrivast have you run the sinppet already? beacsue for me its working just fine

Comment: @Basickz I'm unable to see the boxes going under each other as you have shown in the picture. For me, they are always next to each other

Comment: @AdityaSrivast, the problem is that when i put a comment in comment box 1 (left one) the comment will be shown under the left comment box and my second comment box (right one) will be put under the comment i posted.

Comment: i think i got the problem, when i put a comment in comment box 1 my `#second div` will me put into my first div